# Drop coordinates in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want the coordinates of the finger when user drops the object and remove the finger.

I got the position of user when touch the screen but not getting the coordinates when user remove the finger

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're doing. But `onTouchListener` gives you all the information about any user interaction event. `Event.ACTION_DOWN` is when the user starts the event, and `Event.ACTION_UP` is when the user ends the event (removes their finger)